# C++ binary predicate implementation requirements for std::search

Tags: c++, c++11

On this [site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) it states that one of the constraints for a binary predicate passed into `std::search` is that:

> The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that objects of types ForwardIt1 and ForwardIt2 can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both Type1 and Type2.

However, in the C++ International Standard documentation I see no reference to such a constraint. I am wondering if this constraint is explicitly stated in the C++ International Standard documentation which section it is under. In addition if it is not then why is this constraint placed upon the `std::search` function as isn't it possible to have two distinct types that while not implicitly convertible have an equality operator overload defined?

Comment: @bolov There is no explicit requirement in [alg.search](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/alg.search)

Comment: I updated the title to be more accurate.

Comment: @liliscent yes it is. Ok, maybe implicit, but that is just not here nor there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a mistake on the site.

That parameter description is populated from [this template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Template:par_pred2_eq). It doesn't distinguish between binary predicates that are only called as `pred(*first1, *first2)` from those that are called as both `pred(*first1, *first2)` and `pred(*first2, *first1)`

Further digging:
It appears that [this edit](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Template%3Apar_pred2&diff=93520&oldid=61756) added a named parameter to the [parent template's](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Template:par_pred2) use of [`cast req2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Template:cast_req2), which controls whether it says "both" or "respectively". The `eq` variant does not have a passthrough of this new parameter. I don't have edit privileges to add it in to the template and the entry for `std::search`

Comment: Quotation from website template... Good answer !

Comment: {{cast req2}} is also checking `bidirectional` wrong for this case (MediaWiki's `#if` is a "if empty" check, not a "if truthy" check). I've instrumented the templates to see where we are using this default value so that they can all be fixed (either by changing the default or by suppressing with `bidirectional=false`).

Comment: It looks like the defaulted true is only used on five pages - and none of them should be using it. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The requirement of a `BinaryPredicate` is stated in [[algorithms.requirements]/7](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#7):

> The `BinaryPredicate` parameter is used whenever an algorithm expects a function object that when applied to the result of dereferencing two corresponding iterators or to dereferencing an iterator and type `T` when `T` is part of the signature returns a value testable as `true`. In other words, if an algorithm takes `BinaryPredicate` `binary_­pred` as its argument and `first1` and `first2` as its iterator arguments, it should work correctly in the construct `binary_­pred(*first1, *first2)` contextually converted to `bool` ([conv]). `BinaryPredicate` always takes the first iterator's `value_­type` as its first argument, that is, in those cases when `T value` is part of the signature, it should work correctly in the construct `binary_­pred(*first1, value)` contextually converted to `bool` ([conv]). `binary_­pred` shall not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterators.

There is no requirement for constructing `Type1` from dereferencing `ForwardIt2`. The word '**both**' in OP's quotation from cppreference is inaccurate.

Comment: Right I see that, but I don't see where in that paragraph where it explicitly states that the two types of `first1` and `first2` must be implicitly convertible to a single type, which is a constraint stated by the website. I guess does that imply the link I provided has an incorrect interpretation?

Comment: @cogle I couldn't find anything stating "convertible to a single type". Could point it out ?

Comment: "then implicitly converted to **both** Type1 and Type2" vs "then implicitly converted to **respectively** Type1 and Type2"

Comment: Yes it appears that is a typo on my part according to the link though it states that they must be implicitly convertible from `Type 1` to `Type 2` and visa versa. Which is what I believe @Caleth is pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally see your confusion. Is caused by the way the word "both" was used.

The meaning should be that both of the following conditions must be true:

- The type `Type1` must be such that objects of types `ForwardIt1` can be 
  dereferenced and then implicitly converted to `Type1`
- The type `Type2` must be such that objects of types `ForwardIt2` can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to `Type2`

---

You will find the requirements in 25.2.13 Search [alg.search]:

> §25.2.13 Search [alg.search]
>
> ```
> template<class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2,
>          class BinaryPredicate>
> ForwardIterator1
> search(ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
>        ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator2 last2,
>        BinaryPredicate pred);
> ```
>
> 2. Returns: The first iterator `i` in the range `[first1,last1 - (last2-first2))` such that for every non-negative integer `n` less than
>      `last2 - first2` the following corresponding conditions hold: `*(i + n) == *(first2 + n)`, `pred(*(i + n), *(first2 + n)) != false`. Returns `first1` if `[first2, last2)` is empty, otherwise returns `last1` if no such
>      iterator is found.

Relevant is the condition:

```
pred(*(i + n), *(first2 + n)) != false
```

This implies that `pred(*(i + n), *(first2 + n))` is valid. That means that `*(i + n)` and `*(first2 + n)` can be passed as arguments to pred. This means that first param of `pred` must be constructible from  dereferencing `ForwardIterator1` and the 2nd parameter of `pred` must be constructible from dereferencing `ForwardIterator2`.

Comment: I think we all misunderstood OP's question, in fact, OP is asking whether "**first** param of pred must be constructible from dereferencing **ForwardIterator2**. Your quotation doesn't require it. But the word "**both**" in OP's cppreference quotation requires it.

Comment: hmm... Yeah, maybe the wording is a bit unfortunate. But it is clear in opinion they meant to say *FI1 covertible to T1 and *FI2 convertible to T2